# How to keep info-window of particular marker displayed on cluster?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm using **Google Maps Javascript v3 API** and **MarkerClusterer JS** in my Ruby on Rails application.

I want following functionality in my map. I've some markers on my map, in that map markers forms a cluster when I zoom out the map, and again gets separated when I zoom in. When I click on the particular marker it displays the info-window of that marker, and when I click on the cluster it displays the info-window related to that cluster. this is the current behavior of my map.

Now when I click on the particular marker on the map, it displays the info-window of that marker, now I zoom out that and when the marker becomes the part of cluster then the info-window of that marker is hidden, I want that info-window to remain displayed on cluster also.

I'm using global info-window for markers and clusters.
here is the some code that handles map in my application.

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
  // create new google marker using the latitude and longitude that is passed into this function as "latlng"
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      draggable: true ,
      map: map,
      zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5,
      icon: '/assets/pin.png',
    });

    // add click event listner to the created marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      // clear the previous content of infowindow
      infowindow.setContent('');;
      // close the infowindow
      infowindow.close();
      // set the content of infowindow that is passed into this function as "html"
      infowindow.setContent(html);
      // open the new infowindow with the created marker
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
      clearUpMenus();

    });

    // add closeclick event listner when user clicks on the close button on the infowindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
    // set the map of the marker to null
      marker.setMap(null);
      check = null;
    });

    // add drag event listner when user drags the created marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
      // update latitude and longitude of the marker with the dragged ones.
      var lat = event.latLng.lat();
      var lng = event.latLng.lng();
      // set latitude and longitude to the input fields for further uses.
        form_latitude = lat;
        form_longitude = lng;
      $("input[id=location_latitude]").val(lat);
      $("input[id=location_longitude]").val(lng);
    });

    // trigger the click event manually
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
       // return the created marker
      return marker;
  }
```

Above is the code to create the new marker on my map.

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,markersArray, clusterOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'click', function(cluster) {
             // this function displays the info-window on cluster
             displayClusterInfo(cluster);
      });

function displayClusterInfo(cluster) {
    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
    $('.map-title').css('z-index',-1);
    map.setOptions({zoomControl:false, streetViewControl:false});
    var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
    info.set('position', cluster.getCenter());
    //getTopThreeMarkers() - It makes the ajax call to get top markers based on some criteria 
    getTopThreeMarkers(info,markers);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It'll help if you add some code to your question that demonstrates what you're doing

Comment: Hi @duncan, I've added some description and related code snippets, Can you please refer that? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem here is that as you zoom in and out, the cluster markers get redrawn each time, as they could change what type they are.  What you probably need to do is keep track of which infowindow is open, and re-open it on hopefully the same location as before (bearing in mind that cluster marker might not exist, or it might be in a different location).  What does the displayClusterInfo function look like?

Comment: Thanks @duncan, Please take a look, I've added the code for displayClusterInfo() function. Actually I've declared the global infowindow so at a time only one infowindow will be displayed on the map. When the infowindow of particular marker is open, and I zoom out, it hides that infowindow and forms the cluster and when I again zoom in the infowindow is displayed there again.